# Compare the counts of a column between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
agent_pay   stautus_ind       policy_number 
1011           B                   1    
1012           B                   2    
1013           B                   3    
1014           B                   4    
1015           B                   5    
1018           B                   7    

agent   policy_number      service_ind
1011         1                  X
1012         1                  S
1013         3                  X
1014         4                  S
1011         7                  X
1011         8                  S
```

I have two tables A and B.I want to compare the counts of policy number for agents.I am using the below query:

```
select
    count(a.policy_number),
    a.agent_pay,
    count(b.policy_number),
    b.agent 
  from [AdventureWorksDW2012].dbo.[table1] a 
  inner join [AdventureWorksDW2012].dbo.[table2] b
    on a.agent_pay = b.agent
  group by a.agent_pay, b.agent
```

I am not getting the expected result.Can anyone help?

```
(No column name)    agent_pay   (No column name)    agent
     1                1011            3             1011
     1                 1012           1             1012
     1                 1013           1             1013
     1                 1014          1              1014
```

I also want the data of the table 1 agents because their counts do not matched with table 2
expected results will be like these:

agent_pay             policy_number 
 1011                      1
 1015                      5
 1016                      6
 1018                      7

Comment: What's your expect result?which DBMS did you use?

Comment: I use Sql server

Comment: Yes, what's the expected result? Please add the resulting table you want.

Comment: I have added the expected results

Comment: Hi,I have added a new scenario.Can you help?

Comment: @TheImpaler:Hi,I have added a new scenario.Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what are you looking for :

```
SELECT  
    agent_pay, 
    policyCountA,
    COUNT(b.policy_number) AS policyCountB
FROM (
SELECT  
    a.agent_pay, 
    COUNT(a.policy_number) AS policyCountA
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2012].dbo.[table1] a
GROUP BY agent_pay 
 ) d
LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorksDW2012].dbo.[table2] b ON d.agent_pay = b.agent 
GROUP BY agent_pay, policyCountA
```

Comment: agent_pay policy_number 1011 1  1012 2 1015 5 1016 6 1018 7 I want these informartion as there count matched but their records did not matched

Comment: @TirthaRoyChowdhury if I've got it correctly, you want to count agent_pay based on the given policy_number from table A. only if policy_number from tableA matched with policy_number from tableB . So, the results will be 1011 = 1, 1013 = 1, 1014=1, and the rest will be zeros. is that what you need ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select agent_pay, count(policynumber) cnt from (
Select agent_pay, policynumber from table1
union all
select agent, policynumber from table2)a
group by agent_pay
```

Not sure exactly what you are looking for here without knowing expected results

Comment: But the count of policy number of agent 1011 in Table A is 1 but it is showing 3.How?

Comment: You need to show us your expected results or we cant help - i updated my answer above again does that work?

Comment: (No column name) agent_pay (No column name)    agent
1                       1011                             3                1011
1                        1012                             1             1012
1                       1013                             1             1013
1                               1014                           1             1014                 
 1

Comment: Table form please

Comment: How can put the data in a table format over here.I am not geeting any options?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select agent, sum(in_1) as num_1, sum(in_2) as num_2
from ((select agent_pay as agent, 1 as in_1, 0 as in_2
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select agent as agent, 0 as in_1, 1 as in_2
       from table2
      )
     ) a
group by agent;
```

This will include all agents that are in either table.  You can add `having sum(in_1) <> sum(in_2)` if you want the agents whose counts do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a chosen solution, but since you asked, here's how I see it:

```
select
    coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id,
    coalesce(count_a, 0) as count_a,
    coalesce(count_b, 0) as count_b
  from (
    select agent_pay as id, count(*) as count_a from table1 
      group by agent_pay
  ) a
  full join (
    select agent as id, count(*) as count_b from table2 
      group by agent
  ) b on a.id = b.id;
```

The result should look as shown below. Is this what you want?

```
  id  count_a  count_b
----  -------  -------
1011        1        3
1012        1        1
1013        1        1
1014        1        1
1015        1        0
1018        1        0
```

Comment: select distinct agent_pay,policy_number from 
(select a.agent_pay,a.policy_number from [AdventureWorksDW2012].dbo.[table1] a
union all
select b.agent,b.policy_number from 
[AdventureWorksDW2012].dbo.[table2] b)d
group by agent_pay,policy_number
having count(*)=1
order by agent_pay

Comment: First it will check the counts,if it matches then it will check agent,policy_number exist in table 2.If record doesn;t matches,it will display the agent,policy_number of table 1 @the impaler

Comment: Expected Results:
agent_pay  policy_number
---------  -------------
1011           1
1012           2
1015           5
1016           6
1018           7